# Kubernetes: Replace Flannel with Calico

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and I would like to try different CNI.

In my current Cluster, I am using Flannel

Now, I would like to use Calico but I cannot find a proper guide to clean up Flannel and install Calico.

Could you please point out the correct procedure?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calico provides a migration tool that performs a rolling update of the nodes in the cluster. At the end, you will have a fully-functional Calico cluster using VXLAN networking between pods.

From the [documentation](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.10/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/migration-from-flannel) we have:

**Procedure**

1 - First, install Calico.

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.10/manifests/flannel-migration/calico.yaml
```

Then, install the migration controller to initiate the migration.

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.10/manifests/flannel-migration/migration-job.yaml
```

Once applied, you will see nodes begin to update one at a time.

2 - To monitor the migration, run the following command.

```
kubectl get jobs -n kube-system flannel-migration
```

The migration controller may be rescheduled several times during the migration when the node hosting it is upgraded. The installation is complete when the output of the above command shows 1/1 completions. For example:

```
NAME                COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
flannel-migration   1/1           2m59s      5m9s
```

3 - After completion, delete the migration controller with the following command.

```
kubectl delete -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.10/manifests/flannel-migration/migration-job.yaml
```

To know more about it: **[Migrating a cluster from flannel to Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.10/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/migration-from-flannel)**

This article describes how migrate an existing Kubernetes cluster with flannel networking to use Calico networking.